# Appending a level to a Pandas Series Index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to append a level to a Pandas Series. Say a create a simple Series:

```
 series = pd.Series(range(10), index = list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
```

`series` has a single index level. I want to add a second level. With a DataFrame you can use `DataFrame.set_index` to do this somewhat cleanly. However, without converting my series to a DataFrame first, the easiest thing I've come up with is something such as:

```
 index =  [np.array(["L2" for x in series.index]), np.array(series.index)]     
 series2 = pd.Series(series.tolist(), index = index)
```

`series2` now has a multiindex with two levels.

Is there any easier and cleaner approach to this?

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do it (inplace) is:

`series.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['L2'], series.index])`

**EDIT** there is also another way to do the same thing (not inplace):

`series2 = pd.concat([series], keys=['L2'])`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Comment: Any reason `series2.index = pd.concat([series], keys=['L2']).index` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure this is much cleaner; there's a [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) class that can be used to construct hierarchical indices:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> series = pd.Series(range(10), index = list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
```

Create a new object, reusing the the original `series` index:

```
>>> pd.Series(xrange(10), 
              pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('L2', a) for a in series.index]))
L2  A    0
    B    1
    C    2
    D    3
    E    4
    F    5
    G    6
    H    7
    I    8
    J    9
dtype: int64
```

Or can alter a series in-place as well:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> series = pd.Series(range(10), index = list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
>>> series.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('L2', a) for a in series.index])
```

Or just start with a `MultiIndex` altogether:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> series = pd.Series(range(10), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                                        [('L2', x) for x in 'ABCDEFGHIJ']))
```

Comment: Thanks @miku. That's helpful. I'm typically not constructing these series using the constructor, or the last idea would be best; they're output of things like value_counts().